# Managing Users in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I've created an iOS Developer individual account because I want to upload an application that I've got developed from another developer. I want to allow the other developer to upload the application to my profile.

Can I manage users and add him as an admin to my iTune Connect? Is this facility available only for company accounts?

I saw this which says "You are the only one allowed access to Program resources." under individual registration.

http://developer.apple.com/enroll/selectEnrollmentType.php?t=nm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only company accounts can allow multiple users.

Edited: This is based on experience. If you register as a company you can add additional accounts (via the [Member Center](http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action)). If you sign up as a user, you can only have a single account for logging into iTunes Connect.

This is what it means by "You can add additional developers to your team who can access Program resources." under the Company column on that select enrollment type page.

Comment: Please provide a reference, link, or other substantiation for this claim (not saying it's wrong).  See [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656).

Answer (score 1):

You can also add team members in an individual license. I am enrolled in the iOS and Mac OS program and have added two of my friends to work together with me on an app. The UI shows that this is the way it should be (in the upper right corner is written "Florian Pilz, Florian Pilz", whereby the first name is the name of the team agent [me] and the second name is the name of the user currently logged in [me in my case, another in the case of my friends]).